# Array doesn't clear thus inserts duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$data['subject'] = "Music > Cello";
```

**OR**

```
$data['subject'] = "cello";



  $array = array();
  if (strpos($data['subject'], '>') != FALSE)
  {
  $array = explode(' > ', $data['subject']);
  $array[0]; // Music
  $array[1]; // Cello
  $subject = $array[1];
  $catname = $array[0];
  }
  else
  {
  $subject = $data['subject'];;
  }
```

//This inserts same data multiple times unless I refresh the page.

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO search_history(place,budget,subject,level,datetime)VALUES('$location','$o_rate','$subject','$catname', now())";
            $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
```

To prevent the duplicate entries I tried:

1) to get the last item in the array

```
   end($subject)<br/>
   end($catname)<br/>
   end($array)<br/>
```

2)

```
initialize array
  $array =array();
```

3)

```
unset($array);<br/>
   unset($subject);<br/>
  unset($catname);<br/>
```

Comment: If you tell PHP to stick something in the database it will happily do so. To prevent duplicate entries in your database, you have to structure your table accordingly, and use `REPLACE` or `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY...` queries.

Comment: Also, you're creating a prepared statement without a parameterized query; parameters are really the only reason you'd make a prepared statement for a single insert.

Comment: @miken32, can parameters resolve this multiple entry issue?

Comment: No, see my first comment.